# Spread Operator is not working ...this.state.attributes

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, spread-syntax, react-scripts

Spread operator is not working

```
<button {...this.state.attributes}></button>
```

Getting error "unexpected token this" Below is package.json we have used

```
       {
  "name": "@coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template",
  "version": "2.0.5",
  "description": "CoreUI React Open Source Bootstrap 4 Admin Template",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.0.2",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.2.0",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.2.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^2.0.4",
    "@rowno/sparkline": "^3.0.1",
    "all": "0.0.0",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-avatar": "^3.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.2",
    "react-checkbox-group": "^4.0.1",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
    "react-loadable": "^5.4.0",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7"
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-config": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-sortable-pane": "^1.0.2",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.3.2",
    "react-stepzilla": "^4.7.2",
    "react-switch": "^3.0.4",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "react-tabs": "^2.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "react-timekeeper": "^1.0.7",
    "react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "^6.1.0"
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules ./src/scss -o ./src/scss",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules ./src/scss -o ./src/scss --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/issues"
  }
}
```

We have tried different plugins but no luck.
transform-object-rest-spread
getting run time error.
We have to update button attributes dynamically and spread operator is only option.

[image]

Comment: Are you using create react app. Also can you show more code leading to the error

Comment: show us more code from that Component.

Comment: We are using react script

Comment: The error seems to be not about spread syntax but `this` keyword

Comment: this has value in scope. I have checked that as well

Comment: Could you please share the component code in which you're using the button? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share that

Answer (score 0):

You need to install babel plugin for that. Instead of installing [preset-es2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/), I reckon to install babel-preset-env which works as (es2015, es2016, es2017) together.

In case, this is [the plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/) for the spread operator you need.

Comment: Tried..but no luck    "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4"
  },  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  },

Comment: could you please share an image of the error ? So that I could have more info about the error.

Comment: Updated question